# WinForms chart zooming X-axis labels temporarily disappear when zooming

Tags: winforms, charts

I have a chart which looks like this:

[image: normal view]

When I zoom into a section, the labels disappear:

[image: first zoom]

However, I can get the labels back by scrolling all the way to the right and releasing the mouse:

[image: zoomed, scrolled right]

And then when I scroll back to the left, the labels are all visible:

[image: zoomed, scrolled left]

This behaviour is just super weird am I'm completely dumbfounded as to what would cause this, or even how to debug.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could try to fix this? I'd like the labels to be shown as in the last image, but when first zooming.

Comment: Wonky scrollbar, that doesn't look like the standard Microsoft-provided Chart control.  File a bug with the author, if he doesn't respond and/or doesn't provide source then ditch it.

Comment: It is System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart which I'm pretty sure is standard. We are using .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, if that might matter?

Comment: A minimal example of your code that reproduces the issue and sets up chart might help us figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like others have had similar issues, so I'm going to try combining several answers I found online to maybe help fix your issue.

> John (DevExpress Support) says:
>   It appears that the AutoLayout  feature leads to this issue. Please set the ChartControl.AutoLayout property to False. This should make axis label elements visible.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T328948/x-axis-labels-disappear-in-chartcontrol

> Valdemar (DevExpress Support) says:
>   I suggest that you use the Axis2D.ResolveOverlappingOptions properties. Set AllowHide to False:

```
[XAML]
<dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>  
    <dxc:AxisX2D >  
        <dxc:AxisX2D.Label>  
            <dxc:AxisLabel>  
                <dxc:Axis2D.ResolveOverlappingOptions>  
                    <dxc:AxisLabelResolveOverlappingOptions AllowRotate="True" AllowStagger="True"  AllowHide="False"  />  
                </dxc:Axis2D.ResolveOverlappingOptions>  
            </dxc:AxisLabel>  
        </dxc:AxisX2D.Label>  
    </dxc:AxisX2D>  
</dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>
```

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q489042/chart-axis-labels-disappearing-when-chart-is-resized

> SharpStatistics says:
>   The only way I could replicate the problem you describe is by setting the x axis Label.style interval to a specific value, say,

```
area1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 100;
```

> and then when I zoom in on the chart if the zoomed x axis section is less than 100 I don't see any lables.
>
> loi-se (the OP) replies:
>   Thanks for your suggestion! But as far as i know i don't set the xaxis labelstyle anywhere, i just use: Chartarea1.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount
>
> This works fine in the case of the yaxis but the xaxis seems to behave on its own will. Maybe i should renew my .net framework installation and get the latest version of the chart component? Any other suggestions?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d345d4a3-a4be-4b41-9c83-9a9d9dbb69b9/the-labels-of-the-xaxis-are-disappearing-when-i-zoom-in?forum=MSWinWebChart

This one is for SSRS reports, but I'm assuming it uses the same (or similar library) and supports the link right above this one.

> When designing an SSRS Report using Chart you may notice that some of the labels whether in X or Y axis are not being displayed, this is because it’s so smart that it detects what you actually want (not!).
>
> To display all labels follow the steps below:
>
> Right click either the X or Y axis, Click Properties:
>
> Set the Interval to 1:
>
> Viola!

https://randypaulo.com/2012/02/20/ssrs-chart-label-missing-xy-axis-missing/

That's about all I can find that are similar, without spending a bunch more time researching this. Hopefully something here helped!